# Is there any way to sort string and remove duplicate?

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to make a sorting system in php where if I input string like below

```
Zahirul Islam 25
Saidul Rahman 10
Karim Uddin khan 17
```

the output will come like

```
Saidul Rahman 10
Karim Uddin khan 17
Zahirul Islam 25
```

Comment: First explode using space then sort the resulting array then perform array unique and finally do implode using space

Comment: but name has space inside it. So space explode is not good for it.

Comment: Please add your current input and expected output

Comment: _“but name has space inside it. So space explode is not good for it”_ - yes it is. You are only interested in the very last part for your sorting purposes, so it doesn’t matter whether what comes before contains one, two or fifteen spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$arr=[
    "Zahirul Islam 25", 
    "Saidul Rahman 10", 
    "Karim Uddin khan 17"
];
$new_arr=[];

for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
    $strArray = explode(' ',$arr[$i]);
    $lastElement = end($strArray);
    $new_arr[$arr[$i]]=$lastElement;
}

asort($new_arr);




print_r($new_arr);

/*

Array ( 
    [Saidul Rahman 10] => 10 
    [Karim Uddin khan 17] => 17 
    [Zahirul Islam 25] => 25 
    )
*/
```